# C++ books for beginners in 2020

Tags: c++, c++20

Hello all Stacoverflow members!

I guess this question have been asked a lot in the past but when I searched at "C++ Books" I only got threads from 2008 and up to 2012... I also tried to filter my question to the newest thread but I didn't find a thread regarding books in 2020 so I'm now making this thread. And please, have in mind that this is my first day as a member on this site so I'm probably making a mistake asking this question. But try to be kind anyways, thanks! =)

Anyway, I have decided to learn C++. I'm an absolute beginner at programming, I have no experince at all with it. I have been looking aorund on the internet to see if C++ is a good language to start with and some people say yes and some people say that you can start with it but it can take some time. But thats okey, I have time atm.

Since I really want to learn programming and C++ I think reading a book or 2 will get me started more then looking at youtube tutorials, even tho they are good aswell I fell that books explain more in-depth.

A lot of people have been recommending C++ Primer 5th Edition. But I have one question... Is this book outdated (If that's possible) Since it's written for C++11 and there is C++20 now? Or is this book still very good for beginners that wanna learn C++ in 2020?

I really appreciate all the help I get, I really do!! Take care and stay safe!

Comment: C++ Primer is fine. It's about C++11, but considering you're just starting out with programming in general, you need a solid foundation more than the most recent features. You can catch up with C++20 later on.

Comment: Welcome! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question about books, you got a link. Concerning this particular one, try finding out what changed between the 4th and 5th edition, for a start!

Comment: Either of the two ***Introductory, no previous programming experience*** books are good starting material.